# Can't find GNU nano global config

Tags: linux, centos, nano

I install GNU nano 2.7.5 editor from source on my CentOS 6.5

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

Now I try to locate global nanorc file but can't find any, then I create new `/etc/nanorc` but it seems that nano doesn't read it. How & Where shoud I create this file? Is there any nono command that can help me locate where this file should be? (Yes I know that I can create ~/.nanorc but I need it global not local)
I don't see any other problems with this fresh installed nano editor.

*//EDIT//*
I reinstal nano from source using, but **/etc/nanorc** still doesn't work

```
./configure --prefix=/usr     \
            --sysconfdir=/etc \
            --enable-utf8     \
            --docdir=/usr/share/doc/nano-2.7.5
```

Comment: Try to do a `strace -e open nano`. It will show where the executable looks for rc file. strace(1) is a tool to monitor system calls made by an executable.

Answer (score 2):

It humours me that this answer sounds AI-generated before that's even a thing. And by "sounds AI-generated", I mean "talking bullshit, confidently". Before anyone gets upset by this statement, understand that this is me (author) talking about my past self.

So given that an upvote has brought my attention to this answer, here's an improvement, this time written by someone who is now less incompetent. Feel free to look at the edit history for the original.

---

Most programs' compile configuration is written so that the config files' directory is independent of `PREFIX`, but apparently this is not the case for nano. You can verify this by examining the `configure` script generated by automake:

```
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
```

Therefore for nano shipped by your distribution, the configuration file will most likely be at `/usr/etc/nanorc`, which is unfortunately not a standard location.

As of why setting `--sysconfdir=/etc` didn't change this, frankly I do not know. Given that in newer versions of nano, running `./configure --sysconfdir=/etc` will actually print "The global nanorc file is: /etc/nanorc", it is likely this is a bug in the build script of nano 2.7.

Comment: Is there not an easier way to find and open this file? I've spent some time dealing with this, unsuccessfully. Probably this "relatively simple question" hasn't find a good answer because the effort Vs. result from solving this (current) problem is too low (or even negative).

Answer (score 0):

normally when you install a program from source, its config file will be at the place where its installed ,somewhere like "/usr/src" or "/opt"
you can change that whene you run ./configure
take a look at the file named "INSTALL" in tar file of nano source

> By default, `make install' installs the package's commands under`
>   /usr/local/bin', include files under `/usr/local/include', etc.  You
>   can specify an installation prefix other than`/usr/local' by giving
>   `configure' the option`--prefix=PREFIX', where PREFIX must be an
>   absolute file name.